# How do you enable shading windows with the mousewheel in Xubuntu 14.04?

Tags: xubuntu, window-manager, mouse-wheel

I can't seem to find a way to shade the windows by scrolling up on the title bar.  This is a feature I've been using for the longest time, but the closest I could achieve in this release was double-clicking the title to shade.

If it helps, it looks like Xubuntu 14.04 uses Xfdesktop 4.11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable/disable the window rollup on mousewheel feature: Open the Settings Manager Scroll down to Other and select Settings Editor

Select the xfwm4 option, and check/uncheck the mousewheel_rollup option. This worked for me.